# Setting default / variations of styling for buttons with React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

This is my first time using React Bootstrap properly and I am struggling to structure my front-end code to overwrite React Bootstrap's default styling.

The main issue is, I have a global index.css file where I want to hold my default styling for buttons etc which gets imported in the index.js file. But because in individual components I am importing the React Bootstrap components, my custom styling is obviously being overwritten by Bootstrap's. I'm assuming importing the global CSS file after importing the React components would work but I don't want to do this across every component.

Ideally, I'd like a simple way of having a default custom styling and variational styling without having to use !important.

Simply, this is how my React app is structured:

```
components /
    Component.js
pages /
    Home.js
    Home.css
App.js
index.js
index.css (global css)
```

Hope there is an easy solution out there!

I've tried to add default styling without !important in the global css file but it just gets overwritten.

Comment: I had encountered such a problem and the way to go about is to indeed use `!important` or just deal with it and style your app using the pre-made styles by React Bootstrap. When you use this library it's as good as it gets - they have premade styles and you'd have to use them. The other alternative is to use different styling library that allows for more freedom but all the CSS is up to you.